# How do I create a new file in windows with ABAP?

Tags: abap

this is my code

```
IF sy-ucomm = 'BTNL'.

    CONCATENATE 'C:\Users\moreiramm\Downloads\' ndf '.txt'
    INTO local.

    OPEN DATASET local FOR APPENDING IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT.

    LOOP AT es_fich2 INTO wa_es_fich.
      IF sy-subrc = 0.
        TRANSFER wa_es_fich TO local.
        MESSAGE 'O ficheiro foi guardado no directório "C:\Users\moreiramm\Downloads" com sucesso' TYPE 'S' DISPLAY LIKE 'I'.
      ELSE.
        MESSAGE 'O ficheiro nâo foi guardado com sucesso. Repita os passos.' TYPE 'S' DISPLAY LIKE 'I'.
      ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.

    CLOSE DATASET local.

  ELSE.
```

(...)

`ndf` = as the name of the file txt
`local` = as the local
`es_fich2` = as bd where my data is
`wa_es_fich` = as bd where my data is to save in the local file

at the end... the file was not created... why?

Comment: Did La Caixa started its project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OPEN DATASET
```

is for creating server files.

Use the class:

```
CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES
```

for local file writing.

Note:  CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES is not released for customer use until 7.02 (I think).  It should still work fine on earlier versions, but if you are on an earlier version and are required to use released objects, the FMs GUI_UPLOAD or GUI_DOWNLOAD will work.